# Insert QSplitter in QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QStackedWidget with a custom widget in it.

```
//mainwindow.h
private:
CentralWidget m_centralWidget;
//mainwindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
  {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&m_centralWidget);
  }
```

Now i want to create a QSplitter, fill the Splitter with content and add this Splitter to the StackedWidget.

```
CentralWidget::CentralWidget(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::CentralWidget)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  connect(ui->pbAddSplit, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(addSplit()));
}

void CentralWidget::addSplit()
{
  QWidget* parent = parentWidget();
  QStackedWidget* stackedWidget = qobject_cast<QStackedWidget*>(parent);
  if(!stackedWidget) {
    return;
  }
  QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);
  splitter->addWidget(new QLabel("Banana"));
  splitter->addWidget(this);
  int nIndex = stackedWidget->addWidget(splitter);
  stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(nIndex);
}
```

The result should be a QLabel("Banana") as one Widget of the splitter and the CentralWidget as the other splitter-widget.
But i just get the QLabel("Banana") - SplitterHandle and the CentralWidget got lost somehow...

*splitter->addWidget(this)* is obviously wrong...
Replacing it with *splitter->addWidget(new QLabel("Cherry"))* will result in a correct SplitterWidget...

The problem seems to be the parenting, but i cant figure it out.
Any suggestions would be most welcome!